# list not split into proper csv columns using python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I wrote the following code to split my data matrix into a csv file:

```
f  = open('midi_data.csv', 'w', newline="")
writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter= ',',quotechar =',',quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
for item in data:   
     writer.writerow(item)
     print(item)
f.close()
```

But the csv file ends up looking like this:
[tuples not separated by columns but by commas in one column only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1MHWA.png)

What am I doing wrong?

The data seems to be written correctly inside the tuples, because when running the code it outputs the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSEUs.png)

Comment: You have `delimiter` and `quotechar` the same character (`,`). Try to change or remove the `quotechar`.

Comment: the output is still the same after removing the quotechar, the quotechar and the quoting, and after changing the quotechar to |

Comment: 1) **Do not** uses images for textual data, copy and paste as text into question. 2) Show how `data` is created and an example(as text) of it's content.